Intuition for how $E[N(E[X_{1}])]$ compares to $1$ where $N(t)$ is a counting process and $X_{1}$ is the first arrival time?
Let $N(t)$ be a counting process and $X_{i}$ the interarrival times. Can anything be said about $E[N(E[X_{1}])]$?
I am wondering if anyone can provide intuition on what it means when $E[N(E[X_{1}])]$ is greater/less than $1$?

$\mathbb P(N(t)>k)=\mathbb P(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{k+1}\le t)$ and thus
$$
\mathbb E N(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{k+1}\le t)
$$
If $X_i$ are uniform $[0,1]$, then $\mathbb E X_i=1/2$ and
$$
\mathbb P(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{k+1}\le 1/2)=\frac{2^{-k-1}}{(k+1)!}
$$
so
$$
\mathbb E N(\mathbb E X_i)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-k-1}}{(k+1)!}
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-k}}{k!}=e^{1/2}-1=0.648\dots
$$
If $X_i$ are exponential, then $N(t)$ is a Poisson process with
$$
\mathbb E N(\mathbb E X_i)=\mathbb E N(1)=1.
$$
So, no general statement seems to hold.
